`ec2 describe-images` Returns No Results For Ubuntu 24.04 EC2 AMI's
When using the following command
aws ec2 describe-images \
  --owners amazon \
  --filters "Name=name,Values=ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*" \
  --query 'Images[*].[ImageLocation]' | grep "24.04"

why am I finding no results?

Most likely if you're finding this question it's because you've copied and pasted
aws ec2 describe-images \
  --owners amazon \
  --filters "Name=name,Values=ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*" \
  --query 'Images[*].[ImageLocation]' | grep "24.04"

from one of many sources online. The issue in this case is that the AMI strings have moved from hvm-ssd to hvm-ssd-gp3. Once you change this substring you start getting matches again
% aws ec2 describe-images \
  --owners amazon \
  --filters "Name=name,Values=*ubuntu-*" \
  --query 'Images[*].[ImageLocation]' | grep "24.04"
        "amazon/ubuntu-pro-server/images/hvm-ssd-gp3/ubuntu-noble-24.04-arm64-pro-server-20240710"
        "amazon/ubuntu-minimal/images/hvm-ssd-gp3/ubuntu-noble-24.04-arm64-minimal-20240822"
        "amazon/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd-gp3/ubuntu-noble-24.04-arm64-server-20240423"
# truncated for length

